# How can I map two lists in Scheme using fold right?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am looking for a way of mapping two different lists items using only foldr

```
(map-Using-FoldR '( 1 2 3 4) '( w x y z))
```

should return

```
'((1 w) (2 x) (3 y) (4 z))
```

or in other words - "map" command implemetation using foldr
is it possible?
thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you want to implement the `zip` procedure in terms of `foldr`:

```
(define (zip lst1 lst2)
  (foldr (lambda (e1 e2 acc) (cons (list e1 e2) acc))
         '()
         lst1
         lst2))
```

For example:

```
(zip '(1 2 3 4) '(w x y z))
=> '((1 w) (2 x) (3 y) (4 z))
```

Comment: @user1322801 did this post answer your question? can I improve it? if everything's fine, then please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the check mark to the left ;)